# CherryPy website design

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm trying to refactor my website code into something more elegant.

My current code is set up like this:

```
class Root(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def require_token(token, redir):
        if token != cherrypy.session["token"]:
            self.redirect(redir, "Bad token")

    def require_logged_in(redir):
        if not self.logged_in():
            self.redirect(redir, "Must be logged in")

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        ...

    @cherrypy.expose
    def login(self, username, password, return_to):
        self.login_user(username, password)
        self.redirect(fix_url(return_to))

    @cherrypy.expose
    def logout(self, token, return_to):
        self.require_token(token, fix_url(return_to))
        self.logout_user()
        self.redirect(fix_url(return_to))

    @cherrypy.expose
    def member_area_query(self, query):
        self.require_logged_in("/")
        if not self.test_query(query):
            self.redirect(current_page, "Query failed.")
        ...

    ...
```

One big annoyance is that I have to manually pass around what page I want to redirect to.

- If it's a member area page and the user is no longer logged in, I want to redirect to "/"
- For logging in and out want to redirect to the return_to parameter
- Otherwise, redirects should go to the same page requested (on which I display the error message)

So my question is:

- How can I better define the page to redirect to?
- Does CherryPy have anything built in that might help me?
- Can I use decorators to store the default page to redirect to? Or to call the require_* functions?
- Can any CherryPy Tools help?

Comment: You could just change the code to where you don't pass a location, and just put in the redirect have it point to /.

Answer (score 0):

If they are not logged in, they could just do something like this:

```
def not_logged_in():
    self.redirect('\', "Must be logged in")
```

I can't speak about cherrypy itself, but I think all your code needs is to break up a few of the functions.